# Read in random line from text file as tweet status update

Tags: python, api, tweepy, status

I've been struggling with this and would really appreciate a guru's help,

I probabaly need a FOR loop to read in the text from a text file, something like the following (lifted from other code).  I will also confess that I wouldn't know the appropriate place to put that FOR loop:

```
for s in twt:
   if s.id not in processed_tweets:
      time.sleep(3)
      sn = s.user.screen_name
      m = "@%s " %sn + random.choice(open('tweets.txt').readlines()).strip("\n")
      api.update_status(status=m, in_reply_to_status_id = s.id)
      processed_tweets.append(s.id)
      print(s.id)
```

This needs to go somewhere within the following code.  My thinking is to select a line from the text file then include that as part of the api.update_status tweet.  Needless to say, I'm inexperienced and I can't seem to get my head around it.

`random.choice(open('tweets.txt').readlines()).strip("\n")`

```
# Using:
# Python 3.9.2
# Tweepy 3.7.0
# pip 22.3

import tweepy
import time, random

CONSUMER_KEY = 'X'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'X'
ACCESS_KEY = 'X'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'X'

#OAuthHandler to get access to twitter developer app data
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY , CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY,ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

FILE_NAME = 'last_seen_id.txt'

#Creating a file and reading last seen id of the message sent
def retrieve_last_seen_id(file_name):
    f_read = open(file_name , 'r')
    last_seen_id = int(f_read.read().strip())
    f_read.close()
    return last_seen_id
#Storing the last seen id from the file created to ensure one retweet to every tweet
def store_last_seen_id(last_seen_id , file_name):

    f_write = open(file_name , 'w')
    f_write.write(str(last_seen_id))
    f_write.close()
    return

#Checking the validity of tweet sent and replying accordingly
def ready_to_retweet():
    print('Waiting 5 seconds for Tweet...', flush=True)
    last_seen_id = retrieve_last_seen_id(FILE_NAME)
    
    mentions = api.mentions_timeline(last_seen_id,tweet_mode='extended',count=5)
    
    #Idea of replying to tweets is Queue data structure (FIFO)
    for mention in reversed(mentions):
        print(str(mention.id) + ' - ' + mention.full_text, flush=True)
        last_seen_id = mention.id
        store_last_seen_id(last_seen_id, FILE_NAME)
        if '#quoteme' in mention.full_text.lower():
            print('found #QuoteMe!', flush=True)
            print('responding ...', flush=True)
            
            # api.update_status('@' + mention.user.screen_name + random.choice(open('tweets.txt').readlines()).strip("\n") , mention.id)
            
            api.update_status('@' + mention.user.screen_name + ' Hello. ' , mention.id)

while True:
    ready_to_retweet()
    time.sleep(5)
```

I've tried a few things but the only one that works is the original line:

`api.update_status('@' + mention.user.screen_name + ' Hello. ' , mention.id)`

I probably can't just plug in the random text line without that FOR loop and knowing a bit more about how the api.update_status works.

```
api.update_status('@' + mention.user.screen_name + random.choice(open('tweets.txt').readlines()).strip("\n") , mention.id)
            # api.update_status('@' + mention.user.screen_name + ' Hello. ' , mention.id)
            # api.update_status('@' + mention.user.screen_name + (random.choice(open('tweets.txt').readlines())), mention.id)
            # api.update_status(random.choice(open('tweets.txt').readlines()), mention.id)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the actual question ?

Comment: The code doesn't pull in the random line from the text file.  How do I code it so it does?  (This is the FOR loop part I think.)

Comment: so you are asking where the for loop is supposed to go in the code or if the for loop is working correctly ?

Comment: Both I think.  The loop needs to be placed in the right or appropriate place and the API needs to be able to pull in a random line of text and post it in response, something like this:

api.update_status('@' + mention.user.screen_name + ' Hello. ' , mention.id)

I'm attempting to combine to different projects:

1. https://github.com/Suleman-Elahi/TwitterAutoReplyBot/blob/master/bot.py
2. https://github.com/Prakhar2100/Twitter-bot/blob/master/twitter_bot.py